# Ошибка прайс-листа в валидаторе Yandex XML

Tags: php, xml

Возникшие ошибки:

> Error parsing XML feed: Not allowed value "THB" for the attribute "id": XML tag "currency".

Столбец 37, Строка 9.

В php делаю даже проверку с помощью `rawurldecode();` никаких тегов, кавычек и всего прочего.

```
$currency = $dom->createElement("currency");
$currency->setAttribute("id", trim(htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($curr))));
$currency->setAttribute("rate", "CBRF");
$currencies->appendChild($currency);
```

Тег `$curr` не содержит никаких тегов, он чистый, но я все равно на всякий случай обрезаю все лишнее и ошибка не исчезает.

Сам XML: https://youatlas.com/export.php (после решения, ссылка будет удалена)

Comment: https://yandex.ru/support/partnermarket/elements/currencies.html

Comment: @u_mulder валюта была указана та, которой нет в списке валют яндекса